# Issue with Google Maps API v3 map.fitbounds(bounds) setting map zoom incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API v3 to display walking routes using data extracted from GPX files uploaded to my website.

The page consists of two Google Maps objects, the first displays all the routes available and a second one will show the route as a polyline inside a Bootstrap 4 modal.

I've managed to get the GPX points plotted and displayed and each point extends a bound object.

However, when I call the fitbounds() method it will usually work the first time and correctly set the zoom and center, any subsequent calls to the same route or a different route will set the zoom completely wrong.  Quite often the SW corner being in the ocean just off Mexico and the NE corner somewhere in Northern Russia when all the routes are based in the UK.

mapData.RoutePins contains a JSON object of latitude and longitude coordinates.

```
var routemap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('route'), mapOptions);

var routebounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

mapData.RoutePins.forEach(function (RoutePin) {
    polylinedata.push({ lat: RoutePin.Latitude, lng: RoutePin.Longitude });
    routebounds.extend({ lat: RoutePin.Latitude, lng: RoutePin.Longitude });
});

routemap.fitBounds(routebounds);

polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: polylinedata,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    map: routemap
});
```

To try and find the issue I added a bounds_changed event handler which logs the raw bounds object and NE/SW corners of the bound object to the console.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(routemap, 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
    console.log(routemap.getBounds() + "\nNE: " + routebounds.getNorthEast() + "\nSW: " + routebounds.getSouthWest());
});
```

The expected result is a correctly zoomed and centered viewport of the route I've plotted, what I'm actually getting based on the console log is interesting though.

```
Map Initialized:
getBounds(): ((0, 0), (0, 0))
NE: (-1, -180)
SW: (1, 180)

After fitbounds():
getBounds(): ((15.190468336327566, -97.72890624999991), (74.04118207833291, 96.68515625000009))
NE: (53.7738, -0.44322999999997137)
SW: (53.71267, -0.6005199999999604)
```

The getBounds coordinates represent what is actually shown but the NE and SW coordinates are what should be displayed.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (with some sample data)?

Comment: Hi @geocodezip, I've just compiled a cut down version of the code which of course works correctly, the full blown version features two maps (one with markers the second with the polyline) it also does geolocation and driving directions from the geolocation to route start as well as an elevation profile of the route displayed through Google Charts and Visualization.  I had already suspected it was a timing issue due to the number of components working together.  I guess the answer is to strip it back and work up to identify where it goes wrong rather than try and fix it in situ.

Comment: Is the driving directions changing the viewport?

Comment: The driving directions are triggered on a button press so it shouldn't interfere. I've managed to recreate the modal contents from scratch and it seems okay still. Next step is to layer that on top of the selection map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having spent some time rebuilding and tweaking the page, I think I've found the issue which is slightly obvious once I realised.

In order to try and avoid screen flash as the modal dialog fades open I've been trying to run all the Google Maps updates before triggering the modal.

However, while the modal is closed it has its `display` element set to `none` which effectively means the div size is 0, so the map gets rendered and scaled to a viewport of 0 pixels.

For reference a previous version of my code used a fixed map zoom level but this was slightly hit and miss as to how good the map looked.

My fix is to run the Google Maps code when the modal is fully displayed using `$('#routeModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {` rather than `$('#routeModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {`

The show event triggers immediately but the shown event waits until all css transitions have completed.  I end up with a slight screen flash as the elements update, noticeably with the previous map still showing briefly but it works.

I still need to build the new version back into the site properly but I thought I'd feedback my findings so far.